# Java: BigDecimal for money and working with cents

Tags: java, currency, bigdecimal

I need to do some fee calculator. One suggested me two things:

- use `BigDecimal` as data types.
- make all calculations in cents (I make my calculation not for a 15.99$ but for 1599 cents)

I agree with first one, but do I really need to calculate everything in cents? This will add some conversion operations and make code more complicated.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the recommendation: Use `BigDecimal` **or** do your calculation in cents (e.g., with an `int` or `long`).

Comment: second one may make it complicated, but safer if **every** currency in your application is in cents and only the display (when you have one) uses whole dollars, then nothing bad can happen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are *alternatives*. You should use `BigDecimal`, in dollars.